# Installing tensorflow gpu in anaconda 5.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have recently installed `anaconda 5.3` and it came with `python 3.7` preinstalled. Now when I checked tensorflow website it's says tensorflow does not support 3.7 only 3.6.

> Tensorflow Requires Python 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6

What can I do now to have `tensorflow gpu` for my pc. Any help is appreciated. Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: You should download and install Anaconda3 5.2. Let's say, for Windows x64 it would be https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe. Then you'll have python 3.6 and could get tensorflow on top if it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a **new conda virtual environment** with python 3.6, then install `tensorflow` into that.
At the creation of the new `env` you can freely choose the python version you want to use.
This is one of the essence of `conda` and virtual `envs` in general.

**A bit more details:**

Inside of the [anaconda-navigator](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator) you can choose **Environments**, then choose **create**. Here you can give the new environment name and the  **packages basis** i.e. `Python` or `R` and the versions you want to use it for the environment. Then you have to install your custom packages beside of the default ones. Here you can install tensorflow-gpu too.
For installing packages you can choose `Anaconda navigator GUI` or inside of the Anaconda command shell with [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html) `conda install <package>` or in the Anaconda command shell `pip install <package>`. 
In general you should prefer Anaconda package management i.e. GUI or conda to the package versions be consistent, what conda manages well. In some cases -choose always the package developer's suggestion- however, you may choose pip install.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the process? It will be really helpful for me and future readers. I don't know much about virtual envs.

Comment: @user214 I hope it is useful for you and anyone. If you find it useful please accept answer too.

Comment: Do I have to install all inbuilt packages that came with anaconda again for this new virtual env?

Comment: @user214 No, you have to install the packages you need. Either you know what you need or it will turn out when you try to run your code in the form of "no module installed" or so error message. Then you will know what you have to install yet as a dependency any of the packages you use.